# $location.search() - how to use params from scope inside $scope.$watch function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I need to pass function variable into `$scope` and reuse it inside `$scope.$watch`. I don't know why my whole `$scope` get resetting all the time in first example.

Living example of my problem:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IFZCEL)

Working version: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CFbffp)

Changes are made only inside controller.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `$scope.searchParameters = parameters;` inside your searchParameters function scope. So you are assigning the parameters to that variable reference. I think you need a separate variable for the function, and a separate variable for the object you're setting. Furthermore, you need to assign the function to scope (outside of the function) ,so you can call it after instantiation.

Comment: $scope is global. And declaration of `$scope.searchParameters = {};` is in line 7, outside function.

Comment: and no, $scope is not exactly global

Comment: It is like 'this' - it changes depending on the current scope.

Comment: [Aight, it works](https://plnkr.co/edit/FXZNT9). I'll see if it works in whole project. Cause thats only simple example.

Comment: Still got issues, I'll make another ask, cause u solved this problem, but not whole problem tbh. I though I did not cut too much code. I'll put link here after I make ask if u wanna dig into second one as well.